# Bot Crashed When you dont mention

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have this command on my bot where you can mute someone using the command g!mute   where the 'user' is mentioned using @. However, if you don't mention e.g GeoGeo instead of @GeoGeo, it causes the bot to crash. I know you need to put .catch(console.error); somewhere, but I'm not sure where. Thanks in advance. The Error is

```js
let person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1]))
                                                                                             ^

TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function
```

Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms');

module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    description: "this is mute command",
    execute(message, args){
        
        if(!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name ==="Staff", "Head Staff", "Owner", "Co-Owner")) return message.channel.send(`YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMISSION TO DO THAT`)

        let members = args[0];
        if(!members) return message.reply("g!mute <user> <time>")
        
        let person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1]))
        if(!person) return message.reply("That person is not in the server!");

        let mainrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Fans");
        let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "muted");

        if(!muterole) return message.reply("That role does not exist");

        let time = args[1];
        if(!time){
            return message.reply("g!mute <user> <time>");
        }

        person.roles.remove(mainrole.id);
        person.roles.add(muterole.id);

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle ("Muted:")
                .setDescription (`${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`)
                .setColor(0x01B8FF)
                message.channel.send(embed);

        setTimeout(function(){
            person.roles.add(mainrole.id)
            person.roles.remove(muterole.id)

            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle ("Muted:")
            .setDescription (`${person.user.tag} has been unmuted`)
            .setColor(0x01B8FF)
            message.channel.send(embed);
            
        }, ms(time));

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're crashing, you're getting an error. The error tells you the exact problem and what line to change. It's the first second and third place to look to figure out how to fix the problem, and you should absolutely share it with us too if you're running into problems.

Comment: I added the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When faced with an error like: `TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function`

The logical thing to do is check the docs to see that `message.guild.members` really has a function named `get`. Here's the docs: https://discord.js.org/#docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager

No `get`. But there is a `cache` like you use elsewhere in the code. Just by checking over the docs you can tell that your existing code is wrong (it's outdated) and you need to use `cache` like you do elsewhere in your code:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1])
```